# Is "there is no absolute best answer to" idiomatic? Is there any better alternative for it?

Tags: meaning, idioms

As implied by the question's title, I want to know weather the following phrase is idiomatic or not?

"there is no absolute best answer to"

For instance, in this sentence:

> I believe that **there is no absolute best answer to** this question, however, based on my personal conjecture ....

Is it a better idea to use "general", "ultimate", or "universal" instead of "absolute" or not?

Comment: People express themselves in such a way (including with *absolute*). It may employ redundancies in meaning, but this does not render it ungrammatical. A specific context could call for some users to resort to redundancies in meaning in an attempt to assert one's opinion. It seems simpler and to just say 'There is no ultimate answer to this question.'

Comment: Just to be clear that the sentence is saying what you intend, could you complete the sentence? I am skeptical of the use of _personal conjecture_.

Comment: @200_success> I don't think that the omitted part of this sentence has a considerable influence on the answers to my question, however, in response to your question I should say, I think we can finish it in many ways, including "... living close to the transportation system is a better idea.", or "... helping poor people is a better action.".

Answer (score 1):

*Absolute best* is a common phrase in informal speech or writing.  The grammar doesn't seem to be exactly correct because *absolute* is an adjective that seems to be modifying the adjective *best*.  So perhaps it should be *absolutely best*, though I can't say I've ever heard anyone say that.  In formal writing I would suggest using a different phrase, perhaps one that explains more clearly exactly what you mean:

> There is no single answer that is best in all situations.

You could say *general answer* or *universal answer*; this suggests an answer that applies in all situations (but is not necessarily the *best* answer!).  I've never heard anyone use *general* or *universal* together with *best*.  *Ultimate* is a bit different as it literally means *last* or *final*.

Comment: It also seems not quite right because "absolute" is used to modify a superlative ("best"), which by the rules you shouldn't do. That's what marks it as emphatic. Whereas something like "vey unique" is not emphatic, it's just redundant.  In the example, one might instead say "there's no one best answer". In essence this says there could be a "tie for first", with several best answers.